# How to convert decimal number to binary number?

Tags: erlang

How can I convert a decimal number to binary number in erlang, example:

```
convert(10) =  [0,1,0,1]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the integer to a string in arbitrary base using `integer_to_list/2`, then subtract `$0` from each character to convert the characters to their integer value (will only work for bases < 10), and finally reverse it:

```
1> A = 10.
10
2> lists:reverse([N - $0 || N <- integer_to_list(A, 2)]).
[0,1,0,1]
3> B = 1234.
1234
4> lists:reverse([N - $0 || N <- integer_to_list(B, 2)]).
[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
```